# Assign src as the txt file content by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, attributes, constants, console.log

I have a file, name: **1.txt**

In that .txt file I have a URL in the first line: https://example.com/logo.png

In this HTML code:

```
<img id= 'summer' src=''>
```

I want to assign the URL of that file as **src** by JavaScript. How can I do that? Any good idea?

I tried the following JavaScript code (But, it doesn't work):

```js
const response = await fetch('1.txt');
const data = await response.text();
console.log(data);
$("#summer").attr('src', console.log(data));
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of `console.log()` is always `undefined`

If you want to use the value of `data` as your attribute, then use the value of `data` and not of `console.log(data)`!

Comment: const response = await fetch('1.txt');
const data = await response.text();
console.log(data);
$("#summer").attr('src', data); this is also not working.

Comment: @MasudRana — Then something else must be wrong. Do some basic debugging. Look at the value of `data`. Make sure it is exactly what you want (and doesn't have anything like extra whitespace in it). Check that the attribute is updating in the DOM. Check the Network tab to see what URL is requested for the img.

Comment: The content of 1.txt is not assigned as javascript variable.